# Python return function error

Tags: python, django

While running this function to validate captcha key and value i am not able to return 
it show error like this
"AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'status_code'"

```
def validate(request):
 id=request.GET.get('id','')
 key=request.GET.get('key','') 
 captchavalue = mc.get(str(id))

 if captchavalue == key:

     return True

 else:

     return False
```

Comment: Where is status_code in your code excerpt?

Comment: Views are supposed to return HttpResponse objects, not booleans.  What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the code and the error, I assume that `validate` is a view. A view must always return a `HttpResponse`. So if you want to return a response indicating a boolean value, indicating if `captchavalue == key`, do:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def validate(request):
 id=request.GET.get('id','')
 key=request.GET.get('key','') 
 captchavalue = mc.get(str(id))

 return HttpResponse(captchavalue == key)
```

I'm not 100% sure about the import line, but it's something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much Django, but it seems it expects you to return a [response object](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/HttpResponse) instead of a bool value (True / False).

Maybe your code should like more like this:

```
if captchvalue == key:
    return HttpResponse('HTML Page saying OK')
else:
    return HttpResponse('HTML Page saying Error')
```